# adding new key value is not working

Tags: php, arrays, json

This is my json [link](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=e710784749a34cd2a41260bc92a7dcd2) which stored in variable named `$onceBooking`.

I want to count total booking days. If `booking` array is empty then add `total_days = 0` but but if it is not empty then i am counting the unique `booking_slots` and adding them into main array. I am getting the correct count but when i am adding this into main it showing me this error.
[image]

```
        $data = json_decode($onceBooking);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        if (count($data[$i]->bookings) == 0) {
            $data[$i]->total_days = 0;
        } else {
            $bookings = $data[$i]->bookings;
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($bookings); $j++) {
                $booking_slots = $bookings[$j]->booking_slots;
                $final_array = array();
                $uniquekeys = array();
                foreach ($booking_slots as $key => $data) {
                    if (!in_array($data->date, $uniquekeys)) {
                        $uniquekeys[] = $data->date;
                        $final_array[$key] = $data;
                    }
                }
            }
            $data[$i]->total_days = count($final_array);
        }
    }
    return $data;
```

Comment: the error message is telling you exactly what is wrong. You are trying to use array function on an object that is not an array. Find what object it is and make it an array or use another function.

Comment: While a link to a website might be beneficial *in addition to code **in the question itself***, a link should not be the only source for some information. Questions on SO *must be* self-contained. Questions which *require* information from off-site resources are useless once those resources change, or go dead. The point of SO (SE) is to create a repository of Q&A which is valuable to *future* visitors. As such, any questions where an off-site resource is *required* to understand the question should be voted/flagged for closure as "too broad", "unclear", "no MCVE", or other appropriate reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your call to json_decode() to return an array by adding `true` as the 2nd argument.

```
// change this
$data = json_decode($onceBooking);

// to this
$data = json_decode($onceBooking, true);
```